# R: How to visualize the top 5 values in a given column across regions

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

This is a question to what I thought would have been an easy task, but nonetheless one that I have not been able to wrap my head around.

I want to make a plot, where the top five partners for a given organisation are listed pr. regional office. 
Bear in mind that in my actual data there are over 700 partners 5 Regional Offices.

Suppose my data looks like this, where I have 8 values for Partners:

```
Partner <- c(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, A, A, B, B, C, D, E, G, G, H, I, F)
Region_Off <-c(AU, BE, CA, DK, EU, FR, GER, AU, AU , BE, BE, CA, DK, EU, 
GER, GER, HK, IR, FR)
```

What I have tried to do:

```
Top_Partners <- MY_df %>%
  count(Partner)%>%
  arrange(Partner) %>%
  arrange(n) %>%
  head(n=5) %>%
  facet_wrap(~ Region_Off)
```

And I have tried:

```
Top_Partners <- MY_df %>%
  select(Region_abb, Partner, Context)

dat2 <- as.data.frame(apply(Top_Partners, 2, function (x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]))
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this pr. regional office...

And then somehow plot this in order to make a bar chart - though I am not sure where to plot the function geom_bar in the above solution.

I hope that someone can help me move on from here.

Thank you

Comment: There are 19 `Partner` and 20 `Region_Off` in your posted data. Also, if you want the top (most frequent) you need `tail`, not `head`.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to respond to your question as your example is not reproducible. We would need a subset of `MY_df` and to know what the `Context` variable is.

Is the following data frame what you try to get?

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data_frame(
  Region_Off = sample(c("AU", "BE", "CA", "DK", "EU", "FR", "GER", "HK", "IR"), 500, replace = T),
  Partner = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 500, replace = T)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(Region_Off) %>% 
  count(Partner) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  slice(1:5)
```

Comment: Hi nael_kl - It looks like what I was trying to do, however, when I use slice, I receive the error message: 
Error in UseMethod("slice") : no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

Comment: Also I added the Context variable, which is a dichotomous variable (humanitarian and development) - I couldn't run the sequence without Context... I got an error message saying that this variable was missing

Comment: I'm afraid we can't help if we can't reproduce the problem. Can you provide us with your data frame or at least a subset triggering this error message? You can use `dput(MY_df)` for instance.

Comment: Hi nael_kl - I have added a snapshot of my dataframe.
I have more than 5000 obs and 30 rows so it's quite alot, why I tried to condense it to the example used in my original question above.

Comment: regarding the error message "Error in UseMethod("slice") : no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')" I solved that by specifying that `slice` was coming from dplyr, and not any other package with a loaded namespace. You may be able to use `dplyr::slice(1:5)`

Answer (score 0):

This answers **the second part of the question only**, to make a bar plot.

The code used to aggregate the data is the one in the answer by @nael_kl.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df3 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Region_Off) %>% 
  count(Partner) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  slice(1:5)

ggplot(df3, aes(Partner, n)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    facet_wrap(~ Region_Off)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rui - thank you for the help. As I also wrote above, the slice () function doesn't seem to be applicable - How do I move on from here?